# Guardar gráfica matplotlib como pantalla completa

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

He creado un código que me dibuja por coordenadas una figura, el problema es que cuando intento guardarla como PNG, se distorsiona y sale mal, mientras que cuando la muestro por pantalla, la figura sale muy bien.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
draws = [['6X12'  , 1.118,  0.457,  0.125,  0.078,  0.138]]

for j in range(len(draws)):   

    fig = plt.figure()       
    xi_down = 0
    yi_down = 0
    xf_down = draws[j][2]*1000
    yf_down = 0

    xi_up = 0
    yi_up = draws[j][1]*1000
    xf_up = draws[j][2]*1000
    yf_up = draws[j][1]*1000

    xi_mid = draws[j][2]/2*1000
    yi_mid = 0
    xf_mid = draws[j][2]/2*1000
    yf_mid = draws[j][1]*1000

    # Plotear gráfico
    plt.plot((xi_down, xf_down), (yi_down, yf_down), linewidth = draws[j][3]*1000, color = 'slategrey')
    plt.plot((xi_up, xf_up), (yi_up, yf_up), linewidth = draws[j][3]*1000, color = 'slategrey')
    plt.plot((xi_mid, xf_mid), (yi_mid, yf_mid), linewidth = draws[j][4]*1000, color = 'slategrey')

    # Títulos, grid.    
    plt.title('P W '+draws[j][0])
    plt.axis('equal')
    plt.grid(True, linewidth = 0.5, color = 'silver')

    # Límites en Y de la gráfica
    plt.ylim(-700, 1800)

    # Mostrar gráfico maximizado
    mng = plt.get_current_fig_manager()    
    mng.window.showMaximized()

    # Guardar gráfico .png
    plt.show()
    plt.savefig('a.png')    
#    plt.close(fig)
```

**He notado que la figura sale muy bien siempre y cuando la maximizo en la salida por pantalla**, por eso es que, por código, conseguí que se me muestre siempre maximizada, **el problema está cuando la guardo como png.**

Existe alguna solución que pueda funcionar para este tipo de casos?, Saludos cordiales.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Si llamas a `matplotlib.pyplot.savefig` antes que a `matplotlib.pyplot.show`el problema es el tamaño de tu figura, que es demasiado pequeño para mostrar el gráfico al completo. Al llamar a `show` se reescala para mostrarse a pantalla completa, pero si llamas después a `matplotlib.pyplot.savefig` tendrás una imagen en blanco. Ésto se debe a que llamar a `show` implica crear una nueva figura actual y es ésa la que guardas.

La solución es muy simple, almacena una referencia a la figura, muestrala con `show` y después guardala. Para ello usa `matplotlib.pyplot.gcf` ("get current figure"):

```
fig = plt.gcf()
plt.show()
fig.savefig('a.png')
```

En mi caso genera:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]